# Should I put space before "then"?

Tags: bash-scripting

I get an error based on "then". should I put space before it?

```
winning=$(( RANDOM % 15 ))
while [[${guess}-ne ${winning}]]; then
   read -p "guess a number from 0 to 15: " guess
   if [[${guess}-ne ${winning}]]; then
      echo "Your guess, ${guess}, was incorrect. Guess again to win a \$200 Guess handbag."
   fi
done
echo "Congrats! You got it! ${guess}"
exit 0
```

Comment: no. consult documentation on the While loop structure in bash/shell. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-while-loop/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you found your answer, but for those watching at home, `then` is only for if statements. In a while loop you would instead say `do`.

Comment: No I hadn't found my answer. I headed straight to work after posting this.. Thanks a lot for this I totally appreciate.